# Unify Figure and Table Caption Format

Tags: tables, captions

I am writing a document with the [`imsart` style package](https://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html). My figures and tables have different styles despite both being generated with the `\caption` command, image attached. Why is this happening? I would like both to have the same style throughout my document, but am not sure which one and would like to try each. How could I implement this?

[image]
[image]

The relevant code in the `imsart.sty` file follows, but I am not sure how to read it. It appears to suggest using the `\makecaption` macro instead of `\caption`, but this is undefined when I apply it.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% table, figure

\def\fnum@table{\tablename~\thetable}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{4\p@}

\renewenvironment{table}
               {\let\@makecaption\@maketablecaption\@float{table}}
               {\end@float}
\renewenvironment{table*}
               {\let\@makecaption\@maketablecaption\@dblfloat{table}}
               {\end@dblfloat}

\long\def\@maketablecaption#1#2{%
      \tablecaption@shape\tablecaption@size%
      {\tablename@size #1}\tablename@skip #2\par
      \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\setattribute{tablecaption}{shape}{\centering}
\setattribute{tablecaption}{size} {\footnotesize\itshape}
\setattribute{tablename}   {size} {\scshape}
\setattribute{tablename}   {skip} {\endgraf}


% figure : use \@makecaption:
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \footnotesize
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\itshape\textsc{#1}. #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \itshape\textsc{#1}. #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \figurecaption@size
  \sbox\@tempboxa{{\figurename@size #1}\figurename@skip #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    {\figurename@size #1}\figurename@skip #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\setattribute{figurecaption}{size}{\footnotesize\itshape}
\setattribute{figurename}   {size}{\scshape}
\setattribute{figurename}   {skip}{.~}


\def\@floatboxreset{%
        \reset@font
        \@setminipage
        \singlespacing
        \footnotesize
        \centering
}

\if@aihplayout
  \setattribute{tablecaption}{size} {\footnotesize}
  \setattribute{figurecaption}{size}{\footnotesize}
\fi

\if@bjpslayout
  \setattribute{tablename}   {size} {\bfseries\upshape}
  \setattribute{tablename}   {skip} {\enskip}

  \setattribute{figurename}   {size}{\bfseries\upshape}
  \setattribute{figurename}   {skip}{\enskip}
  \def\figurename{Figure}
\fi
```

Comment: If you intent to publish your article in IMS journals, don't change anything what they prepare in their "template" (`\documentclass`).It is designed so, that document look as they like to have it.

Comment: Thank you! This is just for a preprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be easier to override the fonts in the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  Figure content
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{Table Caption}
  Table content
\end{table}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textsc{Figure}}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  Figure content  
  \caption{\textsc{Figure caption}}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\tablename}{\textsc{Tab.}}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{\textsc{Table Caption}}
  Table content
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]